# Insert a newline character every 10 characters in a string using Julia

Tags: regex, replace, julia

I want to insert a newline character every 10 characters in a protein sequence :

```
seq="MSKNKSPLLNESEKMMSEMLPMKVSQSKLNYEEKVYIPTTIRNRKQHCFRRFFPYIALFQ"
```

In Perl, it is very easy :

```
$seq=~s/(.{10})/$1\n/g ; # does the job!

perl -e '$seq="MSKNKSPLLNESEKMMSEMLPMKVSQSKLNYEEKVYIPTTIRNRKQHCFRRFFPYIALFQ"; $seq=~s/(.{10})/$1\n/g; print $seq'
MSKNKSPLLN
ESEKMMSEML
PMKVSQSKLN
YEEKVYIPTT
IRNRKQHCFR
RFFPYIALFQ
```

In Julia,

```
replace(seq, r"(.{10})" , "\n")
```

does not work because I don't know a way to get the capture group (.{10}) and substitute it with itself + "\n"

```
julia> replace(seq, r"(.{10})" , "\n")
"\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

So to do that, I need 2 steps :

```
    julia> a=matchall(r"(.{1,10})" ,seq)
    6-element Array{SubString{UTF8String},1}:
     "MSKNKSPLLN"
     "ESEKMMSEML"
     "PMKVSQSKLN"
     "YEEKVYIPTT"
     "IRNRKQHCFR"
     "RFFPYIALFQ"

    julia> b=join(a, "\n")
    "MSKNKSPLLN\nESEKMMSEML\nPMKVSQSKLN\nYEEKVYIPTT\nIRNRKQHCFR\nRFFPYIALFQ"

    julia> println(b)
    MSKNKSPLLN
    ESEKMMSEML
    PMKVSQSKLN
    YEEKVYIPTT
    IRNRKQHCFR
    RFFPYIALFQ

# Caution :    
a=matchall(r"(.{10})" ,seq) # wrong if seq is not exactly a multiple of 10 !

julia> seq
"MSKNKSPLLNESEKMMSEMLPMKVSQSKLNYEEKVYIPTTIRNRKQHCFRRFFPYIAL"

julia> matchall(r"(.{10})" ,seq)
5-element Array{SubString{UTF8String},1}:
"MSKNKSPLLN"
"ESEKMMSEML"
"PMKVSQSKLN"
"YEEKVYIPTT"
"IRNRKQHCFR"

julia> matchall(r"(.{1,10})" ,seq)
6-element Array{SubString{UTF8String},1}:
"MSKNKSPLLN"
"ESEKMMSEML"
"PMKVSQSKLN"
"YEEKVYIPTT"
"IRNRKQHCFR"
"RFFPYIAL"
```

Is there a one step solution or a better (faster) way?

Just for fun a benchmark with all these interesting answers ! (updated with julia 5.0)

```
function loop(a)
 last = 0
 #create the interval, in your case 10
 salt = 10
 #iterate in string (starts in the 10th value, don't forget julia use 1 to first index)
 for i in salt:salt+1:length(a)
    # replace the string for a new one with '\n'
    a = string(a[1:i], '\n', a[i+1:length(a)])
    last = Int64(i)
 end
 # replace the rest
 a = string(a[1:length(a) - last % salt + 1], '\n', a[length(a) - last % salt + 2:length(a)])
 println(a)
end

function regex1(seq)
  a=matchall(r"(.{1,10})" ,seq)
  b=join(a, "\n")
  println(b)
end

function regex2(seq)
  a=join(split(replace(seq, r"(.{10})", s"\1 ")), "\n")
  println(a)
end

function regex3(seq)
  a=replace(seq, r"(.{10})", Base.SubstitutionString("\\1\n"))
  a= chomp(a) # because there is a new line at the end
  println(a)
end

function intrapad(seq::String)
  buf = IOBuffer((length(seq)*11)>>3) # big enough buffer
  for i=1:10:length(seq)
    write(buf,SubString(seq,i,i+9),'\n')
  end
  #return
  print(takebuf_string(buf))
end

function join_substring(seq)
  a=join((SubString(seq,i,i+9) for i=1:10:length(seq)),'\n')
  println(a)
end

seq="MSKNKSPLLNESEKMMSEMLPMKVSQSKLNYEEKVYIPTTIRNRKQHCFRRFFPYIALFQ"

for i = 1:5
  println("loop :")
  @time loop(seq)
  println("regex1 :")
  @time regex1(seq)
  println("regex2 :")
  @time regex2(seq)
  println("regex3 :")
  @time regex3(seq)
  println("intrapad :")
  @time intrapad(seq)
  println("join substring :")
  @time join_substring(seq)
end
```

I changed the benchmark to execute 5 times @time and I  post here the results after 5 execution of @time :

```
loop :
MSKNKSPLLN
ESEKMMSEML
PMKVSQSKLN
YEEKVYIPTT
IRNRKQHCFR
RFFPYIA
LFQ
  0.000013 seconds (53 allocations: 3.359 KB)
regex1 :
MSKNKSPLLN
ESEKMMSEML
PMKVSQSKLN
YEEKVYIPTT
IRNRKQHCFR
RFFPYIALFQ
  0.000013 seconds (49 allocations: 1.344 KB)
regex2 :
MSKNKSPLLN
ESEKMMSEML
PMKVSQSKLN
YEEKVYIPTT
IRNRKQHCFR
RFFPYIALFQ
  0.000017 seconds (47 allocations: 1.703 KB)
regex3 :
MSKNKSPLLN
ESEKMMSEML
PMKVSQSKLN
YEEKVYIPTT
IRNRKQHCFR
RFFPYIALFQ
  0.000013 seconds (31 allocations: 976 bytes)
intrapad :
MSKNKSPLLN
ESEKMMSEML
PMKVSQSKLN
YEEKVYIPTT
IRNRKQHCFR
RFFPYIALFQ
  0.000007 seconds (9 allocations: 608 bytes)
join substring :
MSKNKSPLLN
ESEKMMSEML
PMKVSQSKLN
YEEKVYIPTT
IRNRKQHCFR
RFFPYIALFQ
  0.000012 seconds (21 allocations: 800 bytes)
```

Intrapad is now first ;)

Comment: Don't know about another solution but 2 steps can be change to one liner like this:     `seq="MSKNKSPLLNESEKMMSEMLPMKVSQSKLNYEEKVYIPTTIRNRKQHCFRRFFPYIALFQ";`

`println(join(matchall(r"(.{10})" ,seq), "\n"));`

Comment: So I checked again documentation:
`println(replace("ABHISHEKBHASKERMSEMLPMKVSQSKLNYEEKVYIPTTIRNRKQHCFRRFFPYIALFQ", r".{10}", s"\g<0> sss"));`
here If I replace sss to \n this should have work but instead as per the doc "by using \n to refer to the nth capture group" this is the problem here.

Comment: Yes, @AbhiNickz  replace(seq, r"(.{10})" , s"\g<0>\n")  produce an error, but it is a good solution to insert a blanc for example : replace(seq, r"(.{10})" , s"\g<0> ") is ok

Comment: @Dan Done :) Thank you for your example !

Comment: @DanGetz indeed the time has now reduced a lot ! Thanks for the remark ! Would you explain how did you choose the values 11 and 3 in the buffer size (length(seq)*11)>>3 and the reason of >>3 ? Thanks !

Comment: Why `(length(seq)*11)>>3` in `intrapad`: The output string has 11 chars for each 10, so it needs around orig_size*11/10 characters. The `>>3` is a quick way to divide by 8 (a right shift), and 8<10, so there is room to spare. In general, division is bad for speed (good thing to know)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like @daycaster suggests, you can use `s"\1"` as a replacement string to support capture groups. And since Julia 1.3, the replacement strings support newlines. So it's:

```
julia> replace(seq, r"(.{10})" => s"\1\n")
"MSKNKSPLLN\nESEKMMSEML\nPMKVSQSKLN\nYEEKVYIPTT\nIRNRKQHCFR\nRFFPYIALFQ\n"
```

Comment: In Julia 1.10, this should now be `replace(seq, r"(.{10})" => Base.SubstitutionString("\\1\n"))`

Comment: Even better, the `s"..."` syntax now supports newlines.

Answer (score 7):

If speed is an issue, it might be best to avoid heavier tools such as regular expressions and try to just get the job done low-level, like so:

```
function intrapad(seq::String)
  buf = IOBuffer((length(seq)*11)>>3) # big enough buffer
  for i=1:10:length(seq)
    write(buf,SubString(seq,i,i+9),'\n')
  end
  return takebuf_string(buf)
end
```

Speed comes from minimizing allocation using IOBuffer and SubStrings. Using BenchmarkTools package we have:

```
julia> @benchmark intrapad(seq)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  624.00 bytes
  allocs estimate:  10
  minimum time:     729.00 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      767.00 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        862.99 ns (7.84% GC)
  maximum time:     26.86 μs (96.21% GC)

julia> @benchmark replace(seq, r"(.{10})", Base.SubstitutionString("\\1\n"))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  720.00 bytes
  allocs estimate:  26
  minimum time:     2.18 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.29 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.43 μs (3.85% GC)
  maximum time:     531.31 μs (98.95% GC)
```

Only a 2.5x speedup. The `replace` function is very well implemented!

Another way to go without regular expression is

```
join((SubString(seq,i,i+9) for i=1:10:length(seq)),'\n')
```

Which is not as fast (10x slower, no memory allocation penalty on my machine), but very readable.

Comment: These functions are good for ASCII only strings, as they rely on byte-per-char indexing. But in genomic sequence and the like, it should be OK (or in a future version of Julia with overhauled strings)

Comment: The last join example gives following error:ERROR: LoadError: syntax: missing separator in tuple

Comment: It's a version thing. This example works in 0.5. Are you with 0.4?

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
julia> split(replace(seq, r"(.{10})", s"\1 "))
6-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "MSKNKSPLLN"
 "ESEKMMSEML"
 "PMKVSQSKLN"
 "YEEKVYIPTT"
 "IRNRKQHCFR"
 "RFFPYIALFQ"
```

If you want it as a string, use `join()`:

```
julia> join(split(replace(seq, r"(.{10})", s"\1 ")), "\n")
"MSKNKSPLLN\nESEKMMSEML\nPMKVSQSKLN\nYEEKVYIPTT\nIRNRKQHCFR\nRFFPYIALFQ"

julia> println(ans)
MSKNKSPLLN
ESEKMMSEML
PMKVSQSKLN
YEEKVYIPTT
IRNRKQHCFR
RFFPYIALFQ
```

Comment: The result is an array just like : matchall(r"(.{10})" ,seq)

Comment: This will fail for strings that contain spaces.

Comment: @MattB. my protein sequences contain spaces? So that's why I'm always hungry.... !

Comment: Sure, but I imagine others that find this post in the future will have more general data in their strings.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you can make with REGEX, but i think it could solve your problem:

```
a = "oiaoueaoeuaoeuaoeuaoeuaoteuhasonetuhaonetuahounsaothunsaotuaosu"
last = 0
#create the interval, in your case 10
salt = 10
#iterate in string (starts in the 10th value, don't forget julia use 1 to first index)
for i in salt:salt+1:length(a)
    # replace the string for a new one with '\n'
    a = string(a[1:i], '\n', a[i+1:length(a)])
    last = Int64(i)
end
# replace the rest
a = string(a[1:length(a) - last % salt + 1], '\n', a[length(a) - last % salt + 2:length(a)])
println(a)
```

Comment: This will fail for strings that contain non-ASCII characters.

Comment: You need to use `nextind` and/or string iteration. See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/strings/#unicode-and-utf-8 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I step by the required line-length through a range to format DNA sequences. In the following snippet, the step is 60.

```
last_x = 0
new_seq = ""
for x in 1:60:length(seq)
    if x+59 < length(seq[x:end])
        new_seq = join([new_seq, seq[x:(x+59)], "\n"])
    end
    last_x = x
end
new_seq = join([new_seq, seq[last_x:end], "\n"])
```

If *seq* is

```
ATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCTATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCAATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCGATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCCATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCTATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCAATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCGATTCGACTCTTA
```

then, the printed output becomes

```
println(new_seq)
ATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCTATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGC
TAGCATCAATTCGACTCTTATGCCTATCGCTAGCTAGCATCGATTCGACTCTTATGCCTA
TCGACTCTTA
```